# Probability of correctly guessing student number with checksum?

Tags: probability, random-variables

At my university, every student has a student number consisting of 8 numbers.The last digit is a checksum so that: the sum of 8 times the first digit, 7 times the second digits, ... and the last digit is a multiple of 11.

Let S = ($S_1$, ... , $S_8$) be a vector of random variables, so that $S_i$ = 0, 1, 2, ... , 9 each with probability 0.1

I'm curious: What is the probability that S represents a valid student number? That is: $P(\sum_{i=1}^8 (8-i+1)\times S_i = 11k)$ for some integer k.

Comment: The obvious answer would be 1/11. Since 11 is prime, the sum you describe should cycle through all values of sum%11 equally. Just to clarify, you mean the last digit is chosen so the entire sum is a multiple of 11, correct? What do you do if the last digit needs to be 10? Use "X" like they do for SBN/ISBN numbers?

Comment: You seem to be correct. I wrote a program that loops from 00000000 to 99999999 and calculate the fraction of numbers that satisfy the requirements. It's 1/11. Thanks for the explanation.